Term for non-structural-zero part of a zero-inflated model
One way to describe a a zero-inflated random variable $Y$ is $Z \times Y'$ where $Y'$ is some discrete random variable and $Z \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\psi)$, for some $\psi \in [0,1].$ My question is: is there a name for $Y'$? The underlying distribution? The non-zero-inflated part?

Relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution. The point of expressing the model as you have done is that $Y^\prime$ is usually a well defined distribution, so any term like "underlying distribution" can be used without loss of generality. You can refer to it by its actual distribution, if known, such as the "Poisson part" of a ZI distribution.

In my work, I am supposing that $Y'$ is unknown, so I can't just say 'Poisson part'.
